# Android - Weird TextView Behavior

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I'm a bit puzzled, I'm currently designing an Activity's UI and two of the `TextView` widget in the said UI are acting a bit weird.

I have set the background to `android:background="#CCCCCC"` in order to observe the behavior more easily, this will eventually be removed when I obtain the look I'm aiming for.

When both the `TextView` are empty, the behavior is what I expect from my UI :

[image]

But when the `TextView` are filled with different length strings, the width gets changed :

[image]

Here's the code attached to my UI's row.

```
        <TableRow android:weightSum="2" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCCC"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CCCCCC"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>
```

So far I've tried to change the `android:layout_width` parameter to a plethora of values with different `android:padding` and `android:layout_weight` combination. But nothing gave me the desired effect (which is to have the two `TextView` occupy the same ammount of space).

I'm far from an Android XML expert so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think there is also android:weight... check the docs. That should fix it.

Comment: I'm currently using `android:layout_weight` did you even bother to check my question before commenting ?

Comment: if it is just two rows, i would suggest using 2 horizontal linear layouts, with children of equal weight.

Comment: I did check your question but I said weight, which is different than layout_weight... The answer below goes into it... I forgot sum but that is why i just provided a comment and not an answer. Guess next time, I wont go through the trouble.

Comment: I also did check the documentation for the said "weight" attribute prior to replying and I didn't find anything aside from the "layout_weight" attribute for the TextView widget which I was already using along with the "weightSum". Perhaps if you would've included a link I would have been able to understand your intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:weightSum="1.0"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvDate"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:background="#CCCCCC"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
     android:paddingRight="4dp"
     android:textColor="#000000" />
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvTime"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:background="#CCCCCC"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
     android:paddingLeft="4dp"
     android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:weightSum="1.0"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonDate"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
     android:paddingRight="4dp"
     android:text="Pick Date" />
<Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonTime"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
     android:paddingLeft="4dp"
     android:text="Pick Time" />
</LinearLayout>
```